# Can a hyperlink redirect a user to a new page/component in comunities?

Tags: community

Is it possible for a Community User to click a hyperlink field on a details page in communities and be redirected to a SF record create page or component in Communities?
P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete your requirement,
You need to follow these steps, I believe it will work for you.

**1. Update custom page in your community portal**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_create_page.htm&type=5

**2. Add a hyperlink on your VF page component**
example
<apex:outputlink value="{!CaseUrl}">/{!Case.CaseNumber}</apex:outputlink>

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I will review this. Can you navigate to the custom page using the standard SF hyperlink field?